# GORM methods not available in Grails Console

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.2.1 and can't seem to use GORM methods in the grails console:

```
import com.mypackage.*

MyDomainClass.list()
```

result:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mypackage.ShippingLocation.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: list(), list(java.util.Map), last(), last(java.lang.String), last(java.util.Map), first()

    at com.mypackage.ShippingLocation.list(ShippingLocation.groovy)

    at com.mypackage.ShippingLocation$list.call(Unknown Source)

    at ConsoleScript1.run(ConsoleScript1:5)
```

Is this a version specific issue, or just me?

Comment: It works as expected. Do you have static `list()` explicitly added to the domain class?

Comment: nope, do you have same grails version?

Comment: Is this happening for all domain classes.

Comment: No errors appearing when you start the console? This method is working when you run the application with run-app?

Comment: Yes for all domain classes. No - no errors on the console. Yes run-app works fine.

Comment: I lied. run-app does not work fine, some dependencies are missing that are handled by Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to add

```
pom true
```

to 
`grails.project.dependency.resolution` block of BuildConfig.groovy

once this was done, worked as expected.
I have a Mavenized grails project.